# Phrases for robbery

Tags: english-to-german, expression, culture

I'd want to know how robbers announce an assault in Germany. For example, expressions like "this is a holdup/stick-up/robbery!", as well as "give me the money and no one gets hurt" and others.

Comment: Do you want to become an internationally known bandit? :D

Comment: I'd like to point out that thieves ("Diebe") typically *don't* announce their intentions; robbers ("Räuber") do. Thieves go about their nefarious work as stealthily as possible.

Comment: What have you found so far, using dictionaries? Why isn't this sufficient? Until showing own research, I vote to close this question.

Comment: This is tricky. In the past, you had to shout something unintelligible, just very loud. Then, witnesses would tell you spoke *mit südländischem Akzent*, which was practical in case you were from, let's say, Stockholm.

Comment: A modern classic: *Geld her Handy her*

Comment: Etwas älter: "Ich habe eine Waffel!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One typical phrase for a bank robbery is:

> Hände hoch! Das ist ein Überfall! (Hands up! This is a robbery!)

This well-known phrase [frequently appears in literature](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22h%C3%A4nde+hoch%22+%22das+ist+ein+%C3%BCberfall%22).

A classic follow-up would be:

> Wenn Sie genau tun was ich sage, wird niemand verletzt. (If you do exactly as I say, nobody will get hurt.)

Answer (score 2):

One of the calls to get money from people, typically at gun-point:

> Geld oder Leben!
>   *(Stand and deliver!)*

Comment: Klingt nach 50er-Jahre und Heinz Rühmann.

Comment: Die englische Entsprechung wäre doch ganz ähnlich *Your money or your life!*.

Comment: @userunknown: Und warum nicht nach Mantel und Degen?

Comment: Das ist nicht mein Punkt. Mein Punkt ist, dass es reichlich verstaubt klingt. Heute sagt kein Räuber mehr "Geld oder Leben", wage ich zu behaupten.

Comment: @userunknown: Die Häufigkeiten dessen, was Räuber so verzapfen, kennt nur die Polizei. Und überhaupt: Auch unter den Räubern gibt es Filmaffine, Poeten und Scherzbolde. Ferner ist es günstig, wenn der Spruch kurz ist, die nachfolgende Flucht erfolgt früher. Alternative: _»[Halt, ]Geld her!«_

Comment: Seit wann sagt man im Deutschen "Mein Punkt ist, ..."?

Comment: @tink: Seit 2003.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Ja, die Frage war nur nicht, was filmaffine Räuber verzapfen, die die 50er-Jahre benutzen - ist ja nicht so, dass in heutigen Produktionen keine Räuber mehr vorkämen. Woher habe ich wohl mein Räuberbild? Die Länge des Spruchs als bestimmenden Faktor zu vermuten ist drollig. "Kohle her, oder es knallt" wäre natürlich viel zu lange. :) Wer mit einer Knarre rumfuchtelt, der wird womöglich oft auf das Formulieren der Alternative verzichten - das wäre noch kürzer.

Comment: @userunknown die Frage nach Film-Und-Fernsehräubern ist implizit, wo du eine Festlegung auf Aktuelle erkennst, entgeht mir.

Comment: Ich halte es für selbstverständlich, dass man mit aktuellem Sprachgebrauch beginnt und barocke Ausdruckformen ergänzend nennt oder zumindest darauf hinweist, dass siei etwas angestaubt sind. Off-topic: https://www.titanic-magazin.de/news/powersaetze-fuer-den-bankueberfall-9069/